# Static chunks are not generated in bulid mode in Vite

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite

I faced up with problem in which static files are not generated in build mode. I use Vite and I configured configuration file in a correct way, importing in my html also correct. In a **dev** mode esbuild builds successfully but in a **production** mode rollup does not build. It generate only html file without any js, css chunks. I attached the images that can display folder structure, Vite configuration file and html file.[[[Screens of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE1qY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhqIL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6y3T.png)

I tried to configure Vite `rollupOptions` property and printed the argument of `manualChunks` method and it printed only html file. I tried to delete the last changes in my code to make sure that last changes does not affect for building process. But it did not solve the problem. Because before last changes in my code it built all static js and css chunks[After building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTcfb.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.